# how to calculate a raster mean/average from individual maps using GDAL in python?

Tags: python-3.7

I have 6-monthly raster maps of ET-data as tif format for the months from Apr to Sep; and would like to get the average/mean of those 6-maps as a single mean ET-map.

ETmaps_04.tif

ETmaps_05.tif

ETmaps_06.tif

ETmaps_07.tif

ETmaps_08.tif

ETmaps_09.tif

ETmaps_average.tif (I need such a map!)

Any idea?

I prefer doing it using GDAL package in python 3.7. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have made a few assumptions here, but given that those are true this should solve your problem.

1. All data can fit in memory
2. All images have the same size (and same geotransform)
3. All images have a single band

You should be able to modify the code in case some of the above assumptions are not true

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

file_paths = ['''List of paths to your files''']
# We build one large np array of all images (this requires that all data fits in memory)
res = []
for f in file_paths:
    ds = gdal.Open(f)
    res.append(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()) # We assume that all rasters has a single band
stacked = np.dstack(res) # We assume that all rasters have the same dimensions
mean = np.mean(stacked, axis=-1)

# Finally save a new raster with the result. 
# This assumes that all inputs have the same geotransform since we just copy the first
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
result = driver.CreateCopy('ETmaps_average.tif', gdal.Open(file_paths[0]))
result.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(mean)
result = None
```